# Firebase Testing Data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We've been using Firebase for the past 7-8 months now.

It has been a really awesome tool, and thanks for the effort.

Here I have a question regarding whether there is a way to modify the data without actually writing to DB.

Cause most often when we debug something we always write to our live db, then we have to delete them manually. You can image how painful it is.

So is there like a test db where we can write stuff without worrying about modifying the db?

I can just export the whole db every time I want to write something, then import it back once I'm done. But it is a rather tedious procedure. And what if I am doing something to auth which there is no way to export users data at the moment.

Comment: Did you consider create a separate project for the tests? That way you can use the database (and other Firebase resources) of that project for testing and leave your production project unmodified.

Comment: Hi Frank. Thanks for your suggestion. It seems like the best solution at the moment. But then it is really easy to pollute the test db since every developer is going to write to this db without knowing others modifications. I was thinking if there is a way that each developer can get a copy of test db locally somehow.

Comment: Could each dev have their own testing DB? Firebase makes this pretty painless and cost-efficient with their free level plan. Use a .env to specify database URL and API creds and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi Imjared, thanks for your suggestion. Was thinking about it before. It is painless and cost-efficient for data & rules. But as for authenticated users data which I can't copy and paste easily, which might cause some inconsistence later on. But it seems like the best solution we've got at the moment.

Comment: Did you try "End-to-end Testing with firebase-server", and more specifically "Running a Local Firebase Server" - [https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/04/end-to-end-testing-with-firebase-server_16.html] ?

Comment: Hi Benoit. The link is a bad request. Just googled the article. It seems like exactly what I am looking for. I will give it a deep dive. Thanks Benoit!

Comment: @Well Looking forward to read your feedback... Sorry for the error in link. [End-to-end Testing with firebase-server](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/04/end-to-end-testing-with-firebase-server_16.html) seems better. I put it as an answer too, feel free to accept/upvote or not.

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase blog has a nice article about [End-to-end Testing with firebase-server](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/04/end-to-end-testing-with-firebase-server_16.html). This may be the solution for you.